# Dynamically change valueAxis in Amcharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm using Amcharts to populate my data.

I have 4 graphs in my chart with valueAxes 0-100.

Is there any way for me to change the valueAxes dynamically to 0-250 after chart is loaded in the view.

I tried [this](http://www.amcharts.com/tips/add-a-graph-with-axis-dynamically/), but it is not working.

I'm using this to change but it is not changing the axis values and graph.

`<input class="form-control maxField" type="number" placeholder="Max value">`

```
      $(".maxField").on("keyup", function() {
        var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
        valueAxis.maximum = this.value;
        chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);
        chart.validateNow();
      });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to manipulate existing value axis than to create new one if all you need to do is to change the `maximum` property dynamically.

Try this:

```
$( ".maxField" ).on( "keyup", function() {
  chart.valueAxes[0].maximum = this.value;
  chart.validateNow();
} );
```

Comment: Thank you for saving my day. I was looking into `valueAxis` instead of `valueAxes`